# Where can I upload my images on the cloud

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, api

Last time I created a website that can upload images and store it in a file but when I try to deploy it in heroku, I cannot upload other images other than the file that was saved in my localhost. But after deploying, images don't show up or save somewhere else to show it in my full stack website.

So my question here is where can I upload my images file or whatsoever so that I can show it in my full stack website. Do I have to use API file links or what? Someone told me that I need to use AWS Cloud or Google Drive but I don't know how I will do it..Any tutorial or suggestion where I can learn the basics? Thank you.

I am not sure if I am saying briefly explanation but I hope you guys understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use AWS Cloud to store images, the logical place to store images is in an Amazon S3 bucket. Once you place an image in an Amazon S3 bucket and set the proper polices, you can display the image in your web site.

If you are not familiar with this service (you asked for docs where you can learn the basics), see the Amazon S3 docs. You will find a lot of useful information, including getting started information.

[What is Amazon S3?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html)

Comment: is this the latest? and recommendable?

Comment: Is it recommended to use Amazon S3 to store content? The answer is def YES.